# make menuconfig when build a kernel

Tags: kernel, gnu-make

I am using OpenSUSE now, when I type `uname -r` it shows `3.7.10-1.16-desktop`. However, when I try to build some other project, it need the `kernels/2.6.21-s915g5-i386` file.

I am not familiar with the kernel source/build. I downloaded `linux-2.6.21`, read the `README` file and ran `make menuconfig`. Then I got confused, can I just run `make oldconfig`

Or if I run `make menuconfig`, what should I select?

Comment: What project do you have that requires an older kernel? Perhaps you can modify one of the build scripts of this project or something to be compatible with the newer one?

Answer (score 0):

Making the right selections there is not trivial.  If you downloaded the stock 2.6.21 sources and want to build a kernel that is compatible with the existing one, it will take a lot of effort.

If some projects need a file with such a specific name as `kernels/2.6.21-s915g5-i386` (which doesn't sound like stock 2.6.21), I would check the packages from OpenSUSE for one that provides that file.  Most likely a package with "kernel" in the name.

Comment: Not to mention that the configuration options change at just about every version.

Comment: And all the options.  Built-in vs module, some components have configurable settings, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by ` such a specific name as kernels/2.6.21-s915g5-i386 (which doesn't sound like stock 2.6.21` ?

Comment: The name 2.6.21-s915g5-i386 has more specific naming than 2.6.21-i386; that added naming usually represents customizations made by a third-party; perhaps SuSE in this case.